# Can't list data from custom data provider in API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm pulling data from AWS dynamo, and I've set that up successfully.
I can see the data being ajaxed into the admin panel in api-platform, but there is some issue with the unique key.
I see this message in the console:
"Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop"
In the display there are two "id" columns, both of which are empty. 
Only one single record is displayed, although the totals is thousands.
The id in my case is an unique string, i.e. 09asd97ga90asdf0909. Perhaps it must be an integer. I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the display by making another id column that looked like the apip examples: "@id".

Still showing to id columns.
If anyone has an idea about that, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The "double id" display is an intended behavior:

- The `@id` JSON-LD property is the public IRI of the document, it is mandatory. Something like `/users/bd98b1ed-3e35-4785-acf6-a48f68c2efad`
- The `id` is the "internal" raw id, something like `bd98b1ed-3e35-4785-acf6-a48f68c2efad`. It may be useful to expose it publicly, for instance to be able to set the id client side (you cannot set the IRI directly, because the URL is always generated by API Platform).

To hide the "internal" `id` key, you have two solutions:

- Use [serialization groups](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups) to hide it. It means that it will not be part of the API response at all.
- [Configure the admin to remove this field](https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/87):

  api.resources.forEach(resource => {
      resource.listProps = {
          addIdField: false,
      };

  ```
  resource.showProps = {
      addIdField: false,
  };
  ```

  });

The the `id` key will still be part of the JSON document, but will not be displayed in the admin anymore.